# How to create a platform or portable code to save your time?

Tags: php, html, joomla, platform

I've created many websites using PHP,XHTML, CSS and MySQL, and everytime I want to create a new website I have to do the following:

1.creation and conception of the admin pages.
2.creation of the website from scratch

but the problem is that , these days we founded a new company for websites creation.. and I am the lonely programmer and webdesigner, we don't won't to use Joomla , or drupal.. and I want to create a platform that helps me save the time.

so this is my question:

1. How can I create a joomla like platform, with many options (style manager, articles manager, categories manager...etc)... ?
2. I've decided to create an windows application, but I don't know if it's a good idea, though I don't know from where to begin.

I am a good designer, but while programming, I don't know the rules to create portable code. so I redo all the work in every project.

thank you all.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Joomla or Drupal? You get the benefit of many developers with a wide variety of expertise. It would take many thousands of man hours for you to build your own platform. Learn either one and you will be able to customize it to suit the needs of each client/site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword is *asset*.

Everything you create for one customer should become an asset among many others that you own, that way each time you get a new inquiry, you leverage the assets you already have to avoid recreating many parts. When you'll have done a lot of projects you'll end up with a descent platform that saves you time and money.

I'm telling you this since you state you aren't an expert developer, because on another hand, you can simply do **one** big product (CMS,...) that you'll adapt to each customer you get but this is damn tedious and require sharp conceptual and programmatic knowledge.

Even if you wish to avoid it, you can still turn to the existing CMSs and master one of them that will become your work base.

My two cents

Comment: thank you my friend, I am an intermediate programmer, but I need basic skills in portability and secrutity,

Answer (score 2):

Objects, lots of objects, everything in objects (models), then views to clear out all of your html from your php and vice versa, then controllers to manipulate the models and pass data to the views. This is MVC and i would be lost without it.

Have a read of: [Understanding MVC in PHP](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html)

MVC has made all of my code reusable, and you are right in thinking it is very quick to get a prototype going. Good luck

Comment: Been trying to understand MVC and it makes sense in ways but could not get my head around CakePHP. If there is a better solution, please let me know, because I much prefer standard PHP.

Comment: Damien, leave cake alone, it pretends to be MVC but returns results as an array !!?? it also batters the DB with nearly as many queries per page request as drupal.  Try CodeIgnitor.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Symfony2](http://www.symfony.com) is what you're looking for. They have great documentation and a big community and very good tutorials with concentration on good software-patterns (MVC, ORMs, etc pp). Its completely free and open source.

Since Symfony2 everything is build up as bundles, what is very handy, because its very easy to re-use them in new projects.

Comment: I agree, but please keep in mind that symfony2 is still in development so for now sticking with symfony 1.4 seems a better choice.